# show a datatable content in a single DataGridView cell?

Tags: c#

Supposing I have two datatables:

-In First Datatable `orders`, I retrieve the list of my orders, like

```
--------------------------- 
'order_id '  order        '   
'---------'---------------'   
'   1     ' order details'   
'---------'---------------'   
'   2     ' order details'
'---------'---------------'   
'   3     ' order details'
'---------'---------------'
'   1     ' order details'
'---------'---------------'
```

-In Second datatable `order_details`, I retrieve the details of each order (like customer, order value, etc)

```
--------------------------------
'order_id'customer'order_val'...'   
'--------'--------'---------'---'
'order_id'  Cust1 ' Value11 '...'   
'--------'--------'---------'---'
'order_id'  Cust2 ' Value21 '...'   
'--------'--------'---------'---'
```

My question:
How far is it possible to create (like a thumbnail) of second datatable and insert in `datagridview` cell (i.e. to replace the words "order details" as shown in the table above)?!

```
---------------------------
'order_id '  order        '
'---------'---------------'
'   1     ' Cust1 Value11 '
'---------'---------------'
'   2     ' Cust2 Value21 '
'---------'---------------'
```

Comment: thanks for good editing @MrW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not difficult at all. You need to listen to `CellPainting` event and draw your contents inside that cell using `Graphics` class drawing methods like `DrawString`. One problem you could face is that you'll obviously have minimal screen real-estate to consume, so you may need to `ScaleTransform` or otherwise minimize the amount of contents you want to display.

`e.RowIndex` will give you access to the underlying `DataRow` that you can then use to access the child rows / DataTable that needs to be drawn. `e.ColumnIndex` can be used to determine the correct column that will display table contents. `e.Graphics` is the actual `Graphics` object that will let you draw your contents. `e.CellBounds` will provide you the size and location of your drawing area.

Here's a minimal example of the `CellPainting` event:

```
private void dgv_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
  var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

  //Get the order row
  var row = ((DataRowView)dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row;

  //Get child rows of your order row
  var OrdDetails = row.GetChildRows("rel_Order_OrderDetails");

  //An example of how information from one of these child rows can be drawn inside the cell
  e.Graphics.DrawString(OrdDetails[0]["CustomerName"], dgv.Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds.Location);
}
```

If you're using strongly typed DataSet, the above code would be slightly different as you'll have direct methods to access your child data in the parent row.